# What's the correct way to use twoWay directive in vue2.0

Tags: directive, two-way

Since vue2.0 removes the "twoWay" parameter and "set" function in directive, how to set back the value to the model.

Vue1.0 code

```
Vue.directive('dire', {
    twoWay: true,
    bind() {
        ...
        this.set(...);
    }
}
```

Then what's the best way in vue2.0?